# NSArray get entire object from key value

Tags: ios

**One must be blind not to see the difference with the above question.**

I have a NSArray like

```
[
    {
        "NAME": "MyProduct1",
        "UUID": 4
    },
    {
        "NAME": "MyProduct2",
        "UUID": 10
    },
    {
        "NAME": "MyProduct3",
        "UUID": 18
    },
...
]
```

Now with a specific ID number I would like to get a dictionary containing only the concerned product. So with ID=18 it would be :

```
 {
  "NAME": "MyProduct3",
  "UUID": 18
 }
```

I'm trying to find an elegant solution, considering each UUID is unique in the array.

Comment: This is not at all the same question. It's about getting a NSArray from another NSArray with possible duplicate values, here we're talking getting a NSDictionary from a single (and unique, see UUID) value.

Comment: Any kind of argumentation would be welcome here.

Comment: Guys with great power comes great responsibility. Please read carefully next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `NSPredicate`

```
NSArray *myArray = @[
    @{
        @"NAME": @"MyProduct1",
        @"UUID": @4
    },
    @{
        @"NAME": @"MyProduct2",
        @"UUID": @10
    },
    @{
        @"NAME": @"MyProduct3",
        @"UUID": @18
    }
];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UUID == 18"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
id firstFoundObject = filteredArray.firstObject;
NSLog(@"Result: %@", firstFoundObject);
```

And the result:

```
2015-03-22 17:15:06.468 Untitled[23770:2311273] Result: {
    NAME = MyProduct3;
    UUID = 18;
}
```

as described here:
[How to search an NSSet or NSArray for an object which has an specific value for an specific property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076477/how-to-search-an-nsset-or-nsarray-for-an-object-which-has-an-specific-value-for)

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, maybe because there is several property in each object.

Comment: @kursus It actually does work - see my updated answer. Unless the result is not what you wanted?

Comment: Indeed it works I'm sorry for this, thanks !

Comment: You don't need to check `count` if you're using `firstObject`.

Comment: @AaronBrager you're right. Updated the answer.